# How to divert data in an iterator into two others?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I know that I can copy an iterator using

`x1, x2 = itertools.tee(x)`

Then, in order to get two generators, I could filter:

`filter(..., x1); filter(..., x2)`

However, then I would run the same computation twice, i.e. go through x in x1 and x2.

Thus, I would do something more efficient like that:

`x1, x2 = divert(into x1 if ... else x2, x)`

Does anything like this exist in python 3?

Comment: At the risk of saying something dumb - do you want/require them to stay in generators? You could simply create the two lists in a regular old `for`-loop; but I'm guessing you don't want to expand `x` unnecessarily?

Comment: No comment is dump if it clarifies the question :-) Yes, I want to maintain the generator approach in order to free my memory as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in tool written in python that I know of.  It's a bit trick to get working, because there is no guarantee on the call order of each iterator you can produce.

For example `x` could produce a `x1` value followed by a `x2` value, but your code could iterate over `x1` until it produces a signal value, then iterate on `x2` until it produces a signal value... So basically the code would have to hold all the `x2` values until a `x1` value is generated, which can be arbitrarily late.

If that's really what you want to do, here is a quick idea on how to do this buffer.  Warning, it's not tested at all and suppose `x` is an endless generator.  Plus, you have to code two actual iterator class that implement `__next__` that refers to this general iterator, one with `category==True` and the other with `category==False`.

```
class SeparatedIterator:
    def __init__( self, iterator, filter ):
        self.it = iterator
        self.f = filter
        #The buffer contains pairs of (value,filterIsTrue)
        self.valueBuffer = []

    def generate():
        value = next( self.it )
        filtered = self.f( value )
        self.valueBuffer.append(( value, filtered ))

    def nextValue( category ):
        #search in stored values
        for i in range(len(self.valueBuffer)):
            value, filtered = self.valueBuffer[i]
            if filtered == category:
                del self.valueBuffer[i]
                return value

        #else, if none of the category found,
        #generate until one of the category is made
        self.generate()
        while self.valueBuffer[-1][1] != category:
            self.generate()

        #pop the value and return it
        value, _ = self.valueBuffer.pop()
        return value
```

Else if you have more control on the iterator call order, you have to use that knowledge to implement a more customized and optimized way to switch between iterators values.

Comment: Thanks for the idea — I might do it in a similar but different way. Anyway, I am surprised that there is no pre-built solution to that not so uncommon case.

Comment: The problem is not it's rare albeit it's not common either, the problem is that there is no obvious solution.  My above solution uses a list to store the values and can have a horrible performance.  The may be awful in time performance as it iterates the full buffer at each new value request.  Using two queues for each category should alleviate that problem, but not the generate-until-one-of-the-good-category-is-found problem.